# Any Java Map implementations that allow for conditional insertion similar to STL map::insert?

Tags: java

I would like to insert a key-value pair into a Map only if the key is not already present, otherwise I would like to retrieve the existing value without replacing it. I can do this with a get(), followed by a conditional put(). However this requires resolving the location of the key in the Map twice (2 hashes, 2 tree traversals, etc depending on the map implementation) which seems unnecessary. Do any of the standard Map implementations allow this operation to be condensed, similar to how map::insert works in the C++ STL?

Answer (score 5):

`ConcurrentMap` has `putIfAbsent` method.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html

Comment: Thanks. It seems like this would have been a useful method in non-threadsafe maps as well so as not to take the penalty of locking on write if not needed. Though it looks like the reason it's included is to support atomic check-and-set, not performance optimization.

Comment: You non-concurrent environment you can add a method for that which checks the previous value.